# USB Connection in Android

Tags: android, usb

My question is that i have Galaxy S3 mobile, PC, One hardware kit. My hardware kit acts as device can communicate with PC or S3 using USB Host mode. I can connect My s3 either using USB port with PC (using eclipse) or hardware at a time. How can i connect both with my S3, so that i can debug my android application on PC while it is connected with hardware kit. Is it possible by using USB Hub??

To communicate with hardware with s3 , i am using USB Host API.

UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

Thanks for reply but i don't have wi-fi facility. Only option i have is through USB only. Its like My PC should be able to detect/debug my S3 using USB & my S3 should be able to connect with hardware over USB.

Comment: please add some more explanation for better answers.

Comment: get ur logcat from wi-fi port forwarding

Answer (score 0):

should be! a hub should solve your problem! and yes you can connect your kit to your phone and still debug it via wifi if that is an option!